# Change default destination folder for the Copy Database Wizard

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2017, copy-database-wizard

Is there any possibility to change the default destination folder for the Copy Database Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio 17?

Changing the database default location via the database properties does not work.

[image: Wizard]

This are the default paths configured for the database server:
[image: Default Paths]

Answer (score 1):

If you single-click in the area of the dialog where it has the destination paths (highlighted in yellow), it magically turns into an inplace editor where you can enter your custom paths. Of course, it leaves some questions. Why did they hide it in an easter egg?  Why don't they just read the configuration file containing the paths you specified in the first place?

My guess is that Microsoft decided to take punitive measures on users who explicitly changed the paths of the database files. Since it makes their coding more difficult to open a configuration file and parse it, they felt it would only be fair to make it equally hard for you to get any benefit from changing paths.